# offset() always returns the same number

Tags: jquery

I have been searching for hours and can not for the life of me figure this out. I'm trying to make a "scroll to sticky" header with jQuery, but the position of the header is returning 500 (the distance from the top) every time.

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/122991/

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  console.log($(document).scrollTop());
  console.log($("#header").offset().top);
})
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's the distance to the top of the DOM, it doesn't change when you scroll on the page.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> offset() allows us to retrieve the current position of an element
>   relative to the **document**.

[From jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Since you never change it, it would always return the same value.

To build a sticky menu, you'll need **the height** of `$('#filler-top')` and **the offsetTop** of it. (In this case, offsetTop would be 0.)

Then check if `scrollTop` is greater or equal to **the height** + **the offsetTop** or not.

If true, add a class `.sticky` to `$('#header')` which makes it fixed to the **window**'s top. And remove class `.sticky` if the condition returns false.

```
#header.sticky{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  var offsetTop = $("#filler-top").offset().top;
  var height = $("#filler-top").height();
  
  if( (offsetTop + height) <= scrollTop){
    $("#header").addClass('sticky')
  }
  else{
    $("#header").removeClass('sticky')
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#everything {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #4fd0ff;
  background-color: #00BBFF;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.header-item {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #effaff;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
.header-item:hover {
  background-color: #4fd0ff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#filler-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #00BBFF;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', sans-serif;
  line-height: 500px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
#filler-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  display: block;
}

#header.sticky{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700|Luckiest+Guy" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="filler-top">Jello!</div>
  <div id="header">
    <div class="header-item">Uno</div>
    <div class="header-item">Dos</div>
    <div class="header-item">Tres</div>
    <div class="header-item">Quartz</div>
    <div class="header-item">Sinx</div>
  </div>
  <div id="filler-bottom"></div>
```

Edit: I, personally, think the following is a better way to do so.

```js
var originalOffsetTop = $('#header').offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
 
  if( (originalOffsetTop) <= scrollTop){
    $("#header").addClass('sticky')
  }
  else{
    $("#header").removeClass('sticky')
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#everything {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #4fd0ff;
  background-color: #00BBFF;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.header-item {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #effaff;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
.header-item:hover {
  background-color: #4fd0ff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#filler-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #00BBFF;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', sans-serif;
  line-height: 500px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
#filler-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  display: block;
}

#header.sticky{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700|Luckiest+Guy" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="filler-top">Jello!</div>
  <div id="header">
    <div class="header-item">Uno</div>
    <div class="header-item">Dos</div>
    <div class="header-item">Tres</div>
    <div class="header-item">Quartz</div>
    <div class="header-item">Sinx</div>
  </div>
  <div id="filler-bottom"></div>
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Just for clarification, the correct way is to measure the set distance from the top and see if it's equal to the scrolled distance, right? How can I do that for elements which I don't know the distance from the top?

Comment: Yes,  the correct way is to measure the element's distance from the top **which will be fixed to a position relative to window** under some conditions. So, technically saying, the demo above is **NOT** 100% correct.

Comment: I add a demo which I think is a better way since we don't have to care about other elements. In first demo, I use those variables just because you mentioned in your question.